# Xcode 4 group file and filesystem sync

Tags: xcode4, filegroup

Is there any easy way to sync the group structure inside Xcode 4 and the actual folders structure in the filesystem?

I have read that some people create new folders on Finder and them drag-and-drop into Xcode, but that sounds like a hack to me. I wish there were a configuration/setting where I could set to make logical (groups in Xcode) and physical (files in filesystem) structures match so that I would not have images, my code, external code, plists, pch, lproj, etc. on the same messy folder.

I also tried changing the location on the Identity and Type panel in View -> Utilities -> View File Inspector and it just made me more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the way you mention is what I do.
Its not great but it works.
Just place the file in the folder and then logically group it in XCode.

**Automatic Folder Content Inclusion**
For automatically inclusion of files and folders, add a folder reference.
You'll see this as a blue folder in your project and now anything you place in there is automatically added to the project.